# Getting batch variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, installation, registry, text-files

1. Hi there. I am busy with making kind of script in batch.
   I need to insert into it kind of "Resume" function.
   I know how to write variables into a file.
   But is it possbile to get it back?
2. Is it possible to get variables from registry?
3. I found a nice BAT => EXE converter. It looks really professional if you run .exe in place of .bat. I would like the user to download .exe installer of my batch program, and install the real program. But is it possible to install it (place file of program) as .exe? I don't know much about .exe languages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly,

1. Do you want to read a variable that was previously written to a file back into the batch script?  Yes, it is possible to read a file into a variable as long as you know the file's format.
2. Yes, it is possible to read keys and values from the registry using the `reg` command.
3. Once you convert a .bat script into an .exe you can distribute it however you like. Place it in a .exe installer, zip it in a archive.